# Error while installing the library from source due to RcppExports

Tags: r, installation, makefile, package, rcpp

I have created my own R package for my company but for some of the users, when they install the package, they are facing the following issue:

```
make: stat: equipped.dll: Too many levels of symbolic links
make: stat: RcppExports.o: Too many levels of symbolic links
make: *** No rule to make target 'RcppExports.o', needed by 'equipped.dll'. Stop.
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'equipped'
```

The name of the package is equipped. Inside the package, I have used Rcpp code as well. When I compile the Rcpp attributes using Rcpp::compileAttributes() to the source, it compiles fine for all the users but for some of the users, it gives error while installing the library.

Let me know if you need more information on the same.

Regards,

Vishal

Comment: Hi Vishal -- you appear to have set up the package incorrectly.  Maybe look at a package such as `RcppExamples` and see what it does differently from yours.  Without a reproducible example we cannot say much more here.

Comment: "Too many levels of symbolic links" usually implicates a *cycle* of symbolic links.  How such a thing might be arising in your case cannot be determined from what you have presented.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel for your replies. I just gave it a thought and built a binary for the library and installation from the binary worked fine. 
The potential problem that I could identify was because of the packageName.dll file created in the src folder after the compilation of cpp files. It was causing the issue with symbolic links. When we create the binary, so the compilation takes place without modifying the source. So for now the issue is resolved. Thank you for your help.